# Unable to retrieve stored procedure metadata for routine

Tags: c#, mysql

When I try to execute procedure from C# I get this error:

```
Unable to retrieve stored procedure metadata for routine 'test'. Either grant SELECT privilege to mysql.proc for this user or use "check parameters=false" with your connection string.
```

And this is connection string:

```
<add name="MySqlCS" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.x.x;Initial Catalog=z;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=y;Password=y providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

And then I tried adding this `"check parameters=false"`

And I get this:

```
Access denied for user 'y'@'pcname.domain.local' (using password: YES)
```

And new config is:

```
<add name="MySqlCS" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.x.x;Initial Catalog=z;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=y;Password=y CheckParameters=false" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

I can connect from MySQL Workbench with same credentials with no problem at all.

Here is C# code:

```
public static DataSet GetTest(string cname)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenConnection();


                DataTable[] tables = new DataTable[2];


                IDbCommand cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "test";

                IDataParameter parCode = cmd.CreateParameter();
                parCode.ParameterName = "Client";
                parCode.DbType = DbType.String;
                parCode.Value = cname;
                parCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parCode);

                //cmd.ExecuteReader();

                IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataSet dset = new DataSet();
                dset.Load(dr, LoadOption.PreserveChanges, tables);

                return dset;

            }
            finally
            {
                CloseConnection();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have all the [required dll's libraries](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.1.html) in place.

Comment: Are you accessing with user root ?

Comment: No. It's newly created user.

Comment: It seems, this newly created user does not have enough rights. You can check for testing with user root or provide grants to new user.

Comment: It still looks like rights issue [Please see](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html) , I will suggest you can give it a try with root

Answer (score 1):

Try SQL SECURITY INVOKER in your stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`prueba`@`%` PROCEDURE `selectEsquemaVacio`()
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    SELECT cve_esquema FROM esquema e ORDER BY cve_esquema;

    SELECT cve_ent,cve_mun,cve_loc,esquema,tipo,nom_loc
            FROM localidades l
            where esquema is null or esquema=''
            ORDER BY cve_ent,cve_mun,cve_loc;
END
```

Answer (score -1):

`UseProcedureBodies = False;` with `CheckParameters = false`

It is working.

Comment: Could ypu provide some more information about your answer to explain it?